# SQLite query that converts Unix epoch date/time and works with DST in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, timezone, dst, unix-timestamp

I am querying and retrieving data from an SQLite3 database in C# which stores its date/times in Unix epoch time

Some are stored as the number of seconds since 01/01/1970

And some are stored as the number of seconds since 01/01/2001

This is all fine as My query can figure the difference and apply the correct date/time conversion

However I am unable to figure a way I can do this to incorporate Daylight Saving Time

Is there a way I can differentiate between DST?
Also is there a way I can get the timezone from the Unix epoch time?

The query I am using is below, any help with this would be great

```
string query = "SELECT case when date<978307200 then datetime(date + 978307200,'unixepoch') else datetime(date,'unixepoch') end
AS [DATE / TIME]
FROM message
ORDER BY ROWID";
```

Answer (score 0):

If time stored in the database is UTC, then you should process you time something like this:

```
namespace TimeProcessing
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Globalization;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double timeStamp = 1000000000; // here you read real UNIX timespamp

            // get UTC time
            DateTime utc = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(timeStamp);
            Console.WriteLine("UTC time is: {0}", utc.ToString("o", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));


            // get local time
            DateTime local = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(utc);
            Console.WriteLine("Local time is: {0}", local.ToString("o", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

            if(Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        // here you implement your timestamp processing algorithm
        public static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {
            DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

all DTS changes will be applied automatically. If you need to convert time to other time zone (not local), the algorithm will be the same, but you need to use [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class to create time zone to which you want to convert UTC time.

Comment: by differentiate between DST I mean the query telling the difference between when DST should or shouldn't be applied

Comment: Still I don't understand that you are trying to say. Nonetheless solution is the same. Use UTC time, then convert it to local then necessary.

Comment: The database I am reading from I have no control over how things are stored. So it os storing the dates as it has been configured to. When I am reading them with my SELECT statement in my question it returns the correct UTC dates and times accept for all the times that have had DST on so, one hour forward. They are displaying for example as 2012/03/26 01:09:32 instead of 2012/03/26 02:09:32

Comment: Date in database is stored as UTC?

Comment: @Daniel you should specify that in your question, it's important. See my updated answer.